# This Stored Procedure from MSSQL did not work after being converted to MySql

Tags: mysql

After converting this code from MSSQL to MySql it refuse to run, the error is Variable not declared.

This is the Code from MSSQL

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[spp_report_connection_setup]
@CompanyCode varchar(50)
As
Begin

SELECT Connection = 'Data Source='+ServerName+';Initial Catalog='+DatabaseName+';User ID='+UserName+';Password='+Password,
    CompanyName = (select top 1 Name from cor_company where Code = @CompanyCode)
  FROM [dbo].[cor_database]
  WHERE CompanyCode = @CompanyCode

End
```

This is the code after being converted but it says. No Variable declared for Connection

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spp_report_connection_setup (
p_CompanyCode varchar(50))
Begin

-- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY
SELECT CONCAT('Data Source=',ServerName,';Initial Catalog=',DatabaseName,';User ID=',UserName,';Password=',Password),
 (select top 1 Name from cor_company where Code = p_CompanyCode) INTO Connection, CompanyName
  FROM cor_database
  WHERE CompanyCode = p_CompanyCode;

End;
```

This is what I have adjusted. but it still gives error saying check your syntax for this version.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spp_report_connection_setup (
p_CompanyCode varchar(50))
Begin
declare Connection varchar(100); declare CompanyName varchar(100);
-- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY
SELECT CONCAT('Data Source=',ServerName,';Initial Catalog=',DatabaseName,';User ID=',UserName,';Password=',Password),
 (select Name from cor_company where Code = p_CompanyCode Limit 1) INTO Connection, CompanyName
  FROM cor_database
  WHERE CompanyCode = p_CompanyCode;

End;
```

Please What am I missing

Comment: You need to set delimiters and what ide are you using? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: The syntax error message has a part where it says "near ...". Can you pls paste what comes after the near word because it gives us an idea as to what the syntax error relates to!

Comment: @Shadow Its says Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4  I use MySql 8.0.22

Comment: @P.Salmon I set Delimiters same thing. I am using MySql Workbench

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks After trying the delimiters it worked thanks, i was surprised why it didn't work the first time